# not able to include dbt.h win32 programming

Tags: usb

I have written a win32 program for detecting USB port device insert and removal.
For this i have used dbt.h header file provided by system.
But still my program fails to link to that and hence my program dont compile.
I have Windows DDK installed on my system and i can find 4 diffrent dbt.h header files.

which one is correct one to connect and how to connect to it.

thanks in advance
Vinayaka Karjigi

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the header file but you also need to link the dll that contains the actual code.

Comment: Very true. Ensure that it matches the include file, if there is more than one.

Comment: You need to link to the .LIB. The corresponding DLL is part of the OS. There are 4 versions to match different OS versions; take the lowest version you need to support. The Vista DLL is compatible with the XP header.

Answer (score 0):

How are you including this in your project? It is possible that you haven't got a search path set for the directory that the file resides in.

As there are multiple versions. I would copy the one that I want into the project directory and include using the quote format for local files rather than the chevrons for system files.